# Vim switch statement indenting

Tags: vim

right now switch statements are indented as follows (automatically).

```
switch  
        case  
                statements
```

I want them to be indented like this, what do I need to changes

```
switch     
case   
        statements
```

Comment: When editing which language? Are you using indent plugins or just one of Vim's generic indenting options?

Comment: C. This is with just Vim's generic options.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to C indenting, try this:

```
:set cinoptions+=:0
```

See:

```
:help 'cinoptions'
:help cinoptions-values
```

Comment: Nope, not what I was looking for

Comment: I want my case statements to line up with switch, not with the left margin.

Comment: It's working fine for me.  Are you forgetting to include the {}'s around the switch body?

Comment: It just suddenly started working, hence why I marked it as an answer. Thanks